# OpenMP for loop when using a different index var to index the array?

Tags: c++, openmp, icc

I'm trying parallelize a for loop but I am not sure how because this loop is using a variable `k` that is not `i` (`i` is incremented by two because I am dealing with two parts of array `a` at a time) for the index of arrays `b` and `c`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < asize; i +=2)
{
    b[k] = a[i];
    c[k] = a[i + 1];

    k++;
}
```

`#pragma omp parallel for` causes a data race with `k` and produces wrong results

And `#pragma omp parallel for private(k)` cause each thread to increment k on its own I.E. multiple threads writing to `b[0] and c[0]` at the same time also producing wrong results.

Comment: if you realize that `k == i/2;` you dont need `k`

Comment: You're right I've seemed to have failed to see that. Oops. Thanks. @user463035818

Comment: otherwise i would expect that openmp has some `shared` that you could use instead of the `private(k)`, though not sharing is always better

Comment: Cause `private` creates variables specific to each thread right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
for (int k = 0; 2*k < asize; k++) // i = 2*k
{
    b[k] = a[2*k];
    c[k] = a[2*k + 1];
}
```

Comment: Also could use `b[k/2] = a[k];` But that's just a different way eh?